# Hive collect_set()

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have two tables: `timeperiod1` and `timeperiod2`.

`timeperiod1` has a schema like so:

```
cluster  characteristic
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        2
B        3
```

`timeperiod2` has a schema like so:

```
cluster  characteristic
A        1
A        2
B        2
B        3
B        4
```

I want to calculate the set difference between the two time periods (i.e. tables) by cluster. My plan (please let me know of any better ways) to do so is to 1) collect_set (I know how to do this) then 2) compare the set_difference (I don't know how to do this).

1)
I do:

```
CREATE TABLE collect_char_wk1 STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT cluster, COLLECT_SET(characteristic)
FROM timeperiod1
GROUP BY cluster;

CREATE TABLE collect_char_wk2 STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT cluster, COLLECT_SET(characteristic)
FROM timeperiod2
GROUP BY cluster;
```

to get `collect_char_wk1`:

```
cluster  characteristic
A        [1,2,3]
B        [2,3]
```

and to get `collect_char_wk2`:

```
cluster  characteristic
A        [1,2]
B        [2,3,4]
```

2)
Is there a Hive function I can use to calculate set difference? I am not familiar enough with Java to write my own set_diff() Hive UDF/UDAF.

The result should be a table, `set_diff_wk1_to_wk2`:

```
cluster  set_diff
A        1
B        0
```

The above is a toy example and my actual data is on the scale of tens of billions of rows with several columns, hence a computationally efficient solution is required. My data is stored in HDFS and I am using HiveQL+Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
select      cluster

           ,count(*)                                          as count_total_characteristic 
           ,count(case when in_1 = 1 and in_2 = 1 then 1 end) as count_both_1_and_2
           ,count(case when in_1 = 1 and in_2 = 0 then 1 end) as count_only_in_1
           ,count(case when in_1 = 0 and in_2 = 1 then 1 end) as count_only_in_2

           ,sort_array(collect_list(case when in_1 = 1 and in_2 = 1 then characteristic end)) as both_1_and_2
           ,sort_array(collect_list(case when in_1 = 1 and in_2 = 0 then characteristic end)) as only_in_1
           ,sort_array(collect_list(case when in_1 = 0 and in_2 = 1 then characteristic end)) as only_in_2

from       (select      cluster
                       ,characteristic
                       ,max(case when tab = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as in_1
                       ,max(case when tab = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as in_2

            from        (           select 1 as tab,cluster,characteristic from timeperiod1
                        union all   select 2 as tab,cluster,characteristic from timeperiod2
                        ) t

            group by    cluster
                       ,characteristic
            ) t

group by    cluster

order by    cluster
;
```

---

```
+---------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| cluster | count_total_characteristic | count_both_1_and_2 | count_only_in_1 | count_only_in_2 | both_1_and_2 | only_in_1 | only_in_2 |
+---------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| A       |                          3 |                  2 |               1 |               0 | [1,2]        | [3]       | []        |
| B       |                          3 |                  2 |               0 |               1 | [2,3]        | []        | [4]       |
+---------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the number of characteristics per cluster in period1 that are not in period2, you can simply use a `left join` and `group by`.

```
select t1.cluster, count(case when t2.characteristic is null then 1 end) as set_diff
from timeperiod1 t1
left join timeperiod2 t2 on t1.cluster=t2.cluster and t1.characteristic=t2.characteristic
group by t1.cluster
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that faster than using collect_set()? It seems that the LEFT JOIN would take a long time and prevent a reduction in the number of rows whereas a collect_set() approach might reduce rows significantly. I added a note above detailing that I am dealing with billions of rows of data (~30 billion), so minimizing query times is ideal.

Comment: @user2205916 .. try it on your data and check for the running time. it is hard to tell which approach would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brickhouse UDF's which have many functions that will perform the operations you described.  More specifically you can use **set_diff** explained in the [Wiki](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Collect-UDFs).  The README file will guide you on how to create the jar file.

You can include the jar file in your query:

```
ADD jar /PATH/TO/JARFILE/brickhouse-<VERSIONS>-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And then use this guide to access the functions:
https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/resources/brickhouse.hql

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 t1.cluster t1_cluster, t2.cluster t2_cluster,
 COLLECT_SET(t1.characteristic) as t1_set, 
 COLLECT_SET(t2.characteristic) as t2_set,
 (SIZE(COLLECT_SET(t1.characteristic)) - 
  SIZE(COLLECT_SET(t2.characteristic))) 
 as set_diff
FROM timeperiod1 t1
INNER JOIN timeperiod2 t2 ON (t1.cluster=t2.cluster)
GROUP BY t1.cluster, t2.cluster;
```

---

This gives the differences in sets, however, you'll need a python function to return the actual missing values from the set. Hope this helps